# Cassandra rangequery, knowing the beginning of start key

Tags: cassandra

Let me clarify it

I have a Column Family, with UTF8 keys like that :apple#NewYork, banana#LosAngeles, banana#NewYork, cherry#NewYork, ... and so on

I need that because they are sorted, and then I would like to get all 'banana' starting keys?

Is it possible or is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

How about composite types?

Map your current rows to columns like

row_key => {
   banana:a => "value you wish",
   banana:b => "value you wish",
   ...
}

Advantages of composite types are

1. They preserve type property while sorting
2. Incase your composite key is `a:b:c` you can query for all columns in the range of a, a:b and also point queries like a:b:c

Now you can perform Column Slice [for example using phpcassa](http://thobbs.github.com/phpcassa/api/class-phpcassa.ColumnSlice.html) 
Ex:

```
row_key => { 1:a => 1, 1:b => 1, 10:bb => 1, 1:c => 2}
ColumnSlice(array(1), array(1)) => All Columns with first component equal to 1
ColumnSlice(array(1), array(10)) => All Columns with first component between 1 and 10
ColumnSlice("", array(1, 'c')) => All Columns from the beginning of row whose first component less than 1 and second component less than 'c'
```

You can do the above said things in reverse and can also play with inclusive & exclusive limits.

Also one point to remember, You can't directly ask for all columns in the range of second component < x skipping the first one

Even row keys support composite types but in case you are using random partitioner then it makes no sense.

Comment: Let's say I can tag all the cities with maximum 5 fruits, i would create column family myCF with comparator = 'CompositeType(UTF8Type,UTF8Type,UTF8Type,UTF8Type,UTF8Type)';? Could you can provide some Hector example ( or other Java) please

Comment: @ca11111 Can you mention your query pattern in your question clearly I don't understand that. Given a fruit you want all cities tagged to it?

Comment: yes, and given 2 fruits get all cities tagged with at least those 2, and same with 3, (maximum 3 tags let's say) I'm not sure Composite can permit this

Comment: How could I put tags (fruits) in composites, if I don't know If I have 1 , 2 or 3 for the city: 
a:b:c => new york, 
a:c => mexico,
b:c => rio,
c => san francisco, and given this, how could I get cities tagged with b and c (ny and rio)

Comment: @ca11111 If you use composites you need to know the number of components prior. Incase you don't then try Dynamic Composites. AFAIK you need to query separately for each fruit and do an intesection at client level. I'll Comment on the same If I could find something interesting

Comment: It's not possible I guess to query the second component: like this: ColumnSlice(array("", 'b'), array("", 'c'))  , where for row_key => { 1:ab => 1, 1:bb => 1, 1:c => 2, 10:aa => 1, 10:bb => 1,  10:cd => 1} would return {1:bb, 10:bb} ? (I don't think composite could act like secondary index?)